# Animate element on scroll not responsive

Tags: javascript, scroll, css-animations, jquery-animate

I have a scroll animation which is working in a 'test' page: https://wordpress-899937-3173615.cloudwaysapps.com/test/

The problem is I cannot make it work on the final page because the height of the page is different and the animation starts much earlier than the expected.

```js
var scroll = document.querySelector ('.curve');
window.addEventListener ('scroll', function(){
    var value =  1 + window.scrollY / -200;
    scroll.style.transform = `scaleY(${value})`;
})
```

```css
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body {
  height:200vh;
  background-color:#111;
 
}

section {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#ff2;
  
}

section .curve {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-200px;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  transform-origin:top;
}

section .curve img{
    width:100%;
  height:100%;
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <span class = "curve">
      <img src = "https://wordpress-899937-3173615.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/curve-white-300x59.png">
     </span>
  </section>
</body>
```

I need help improving the code to make it more 'responsive' to any page height.

How can  trigger the animation from 100% to 0% of the viewport?

Comment: I do not understand your question entirely - you want to delay the animation until the white circle / sun-thingy comes into view? If so, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073). If that's not the case (you don't want something like that), and if you want to include the real document height in your calculations, try using `document.body.scrollHeight`.

Comment: I need to animate the curve relative to the viewport instead of the entire page, like this code does.
`var value =  1 + window.scrollY / -200;`

I've been reading your suggestion but I don't know how to adapt it to my code.

In "non-expert" words I want:

1. The curve stays as it is until it comes on screen
2. Once the curve is on screen, the curve should start shrinking `scaleY` depending on the scroll
3. The curve should be 0 when it reaches the top of the screen and not keep scaling negative (growing in the opposite direction)

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. I suggest testing it out in a separate file, or on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0amo95ep/). I also suggest that you test it out in various resolutions, just to see how it works.

Provided solution / suggestion uses a modified version of checking the elements visibility in DOM, with regards to scrolling and the elements position, as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22480938/6133426).

```js
var scroll = document.querySelector ('.curve');
var factor = scroll.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var value = 1;

window.addEventListener ('scroll', whiteCurve);

function whiteCurve() {
  let scrollProperties = isScrolledIntoView(scroll);

  if(scrollProperties["visible"]) {
    value =  1 - window.scrollY  / factor;

    if(value < 0) {
      value = 0;
    }

    scroll.style.transform = `scaleY(${value})`;
  } else {
    // console.log('no');
  }
}

function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
  let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  let elemTop = rect.top;
  let elemBottom = rect.bottom;

  // Only completely visible elements return true:
  //let isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
  // Partially visible elements return true:
  let isVisible = elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;
  return {
    "visible" : isVisible,
    "top" : elemTop,
    "bottom" : elemBottom
  };
}
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body {
  height:200vh;
  background-color: #111;
}
section {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#ff2;
}
section .curve {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-200px;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  transform-origin:top;
}
section .curve img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <span class="curve">
    <img src="https://wordpress-899937-3173615.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/curve-white-300x59.png">
  </span>
</section>
```

In your original WordPress link, the source code contains a fixed value of -750 as a divisor (and your initial attempt uses -200). Instead of using a fixed numerical value, this revised suggestion employs the initial distance of your `curve` element from the top of the page (`getBoundingClientRecT().top`). This comes into play once the `curve` element becomes partially visible (unlike the previous suggestion, which used complete visibility of an element) - as the `scrollY` increases, the scale factor decreases, and once you reach the top, the `scaleY` becomes zero, giving you the effect you wanted.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working, the only difference I noticed with the first code was the function `isScrolledIntoView(el)` keeps the curve as it is until it is on screen but then it shrinks the curve `scaleY` the value of `scrollY` counting from the top of the screen, so it changes from `scaleY = 1` to `scaleY = 0` as soon it comes on screen

Comment: So it shouldn't flatten to `scaleY = 0` until it reaches the top of the screen?

Comment: Please see the revised version of the suggestion.